# Stack overflow caused by calling a swift closure in another closure

Tags: ios, macos, swift, closures, stack-overflow

**UPDATE:** This bug is confirmed by rdar://20931915 and is fixed in Xcode 7 beta 3.

---

I found a weird bug caused by calling a swift closure in another closure in debug build. My Xcode is version 6.3.1 with Swift version 1.2. Here's the code:

```
import Swift

class ClosureStackOverflow {
    private var b: Bool = false
    private func callClosure1(callback: Void -> Void) {
        println("in closure 1")
        callback()
    }

    private func callClosure2(callback: Void -> Void) {
        println("in closure 2")
        callback()
    }

    func call() {
        callClosure1 { [weak self] in
            self?.callClosure2 {
                self?.b = true
            }
        }
    }
}

let c = ClosureStackOverflow()
c.call()
```

The code above compiles well. However if you call its call() method, it will print "in closure 2" infinitely and eventually overflow the stack.

Could you please explain why calling one closure within another will cause this bug?

Thanks.

Comment: I've posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/hankbao/78a6bd30bd5a7ac0470b) also.

Comment: @MartinR I can reproduce the problem. I am using `Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.49.6 clang-602.0.49)`

Comment: In *Release mode*, the program prints "in closure 1", "in closure 2" and then terminates. In *Debug mode*, the described "infinite" recursion and stack overflow occurs. – Also it occurs only with a weak reference to self, not with strong or unowned. Could be a compiler bug.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for pointing out the difference between the release build and the debug build.

Comment: That is a cool bug. Have you raised a radar for it? Its the only way it will get fixed. :-)

Comment: Yep. I've filed a bugreport #20931915.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this,and it will work

```
    class ClosureStackOverflow {
    private var b: Bool = false
    private func callClosure1(callback: Void -> Void) {
        println("in closure 1")
        callback()
    }

    private func callClosure2(callback: Void -> Void) {
        println("in closure 2")

        callback()
    }

    func call() {
        callClosure1 {
            self.callClosure2 {
                self.b = true
            }
        }
    }
    deinit{
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

It seems that you declare `[weak self] in` in the function,and it cause the problem.

I also test this to call

```
 let c = ClosureStackOverflow()
    c.call()
```

It will output

```
 in closure 1
in closure 2
deinit
```

It seems that it does not cause circular references if you donot  use weak self

**Besides**
I also test to change the function to this

```
  func call() {
    callClosure1 {
        [weak self] in
        self!.callClosure2 {
            self?.b = true
        }
    }
}
```

It will work as well. So I think this may be some compiler bug of swift.

Comment: Did you try it? Your code terminates with E_BAD_ACCESS in my test.

Comment: Hey @WenchenHuang, thanks for your post. Actually I know how to get workaround about this issue. I'm just curious about the cause and asking for a explanation. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I think that this is an compiler bug. I watch the call tree.it just fall in a run loop and never get out. It make no sense

Comment: Set breakpoints in both callClosure1 and callClosure2 then you can see the callback in callClosure2 has the same address as the callback in callClosure1. Weird.

Comment: Add `println("all done")` after `self?.b = true` in the original code and the problem vanishes also. Very odd